# What tokens or variables can be substituted in expressions in Premake 5?

Tags: premake

In the [Your First Script](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Your-First-Script) guide to Premake 5, there's a line:

```
targetdir "bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}"
```

It's clear from context that `%{cfg.buildcfg}` substitutes in the build configuration eg. `Debug`. But is this documented anywhere? Is there a list of other namespaces and names I can use eg. the workspace build directory?

Comment: Are you looking for this? [link](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Tokens)

Comment: @DLPDev Yes! Post it as an answer. Not sure how I didn't find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called value tokens. In the wiki you can find a list of the ones available https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Tokens